# Can I use "ungetc" function with file streams in Win32 GUI application?

Tags: c, c++builder

My question is about `ungetc` function which is a part of C RTL, shipped with C++Builder.

Manual for the latest C++Builder version (10.1 Berlin) as well as for all previous versions, state that `ungetc` function can't be used in Win32 GUI applications.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Ungetc,_ungetwc

Hovewer, no clarification is provided to show why this function is unusable in such conditions. Code sample in manual shows `ungetc` usage with user input from STDIN. Surely, it is not a clever idea to interact with STDIN in Win32 GUI applications. But if there any real obstacles in using `ungetc` not in conjuction with STDIN, but with `FILE*` based streams?

Comment: Maybe GUI applications doesn't *have* a connected `stdin`? It's very likely that the code that calls your `main` function does some extra setup that `WinMain` doesn't need, such as setting up the standard `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` file pointers.